# Ouput the result of Eigenvector to variables

Tags: linear-algebra

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Eigenvectors[A]
```

Result:

```
{{1/6 (-3 + Sqrt[33]), 1}, {1/6 (-3 - Sqrt[33]), 1}}
```

Now I want to set v1=eigenvector 1 and v2=eigenvector 2. How to modify the code?

use something like /.??

Answer (score 1):

```
{v1,v2}=Eigenvectors[A]
```

should work